# CakePHP multiple controllers using same method

Tags: cakephp, view, controller

I have a method (the function in the controller, am I terming that correctly?) and view that I want to use in every controller on my site. Is there a way to make the method global across all controllers and the view .ctp file generic as well? I'd rather not have to copy-paste it everywhere.

This seems like something that should be obvious, so if I'm just searching for the wrong terms, let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Shared/Common Controller Code:**

What you've described is a "Component":

> Components are packages of logic that are shared between controllers.
>   If you find yourself wanting to copy and paste things between
>   controllers, you might consider wrapping some functionality in a
>   component.

See:  http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/components.html

---

**Shared/Common View Code:**

As far as the View is concerned, there are a few options.  If you want the entire view, you can just specify which view to render: `$this->render('TestView/index');`

Or, if you want a small chunk of code, you can try an [Element](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#elements).

---

**All together:**

If you find yourself creating a lot of the different "parts" (View, Controller/Component, Model/Behavior)...etc, all for the same general purposes (ie cropping a photo), you could think about creating a [Plugin](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/plugins.html).

---

**Side note:**

Side note:  Usually, I've heard the functions in Controllers referred to as "actions", and the functions in Models called "methods".  They're all really methods (a function within a class/object), but - that's how they're commonly referred to.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the method in `AppController` and make only one view.

You will use `$this->render('/myview.ctp');`